# 'Find all' method

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like to find all text in a document with a certain color and print it in the debug window.

```
Sub FindText()
    Selection.Find.Font.Color = 3539877
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Debug.Print Selection
End Sub
```

The problem is that it only gives me only the next result while I want want to print all results at once. As far as I know, a 'FindAll' method is not available. Maybe I can access an array that contains all the find results.

Also, slightly unrelated, would it be possible to copy all results to the clipboard instead of printing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the find in a loop. See this example. I am storing the find results in an  array

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindText()
    Dim MyAR() As String
    Dim i As Long

    i = 0

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.Font.Color = -671023105

    Do While Selection.Find.Execute = True
        ReDim Preserve MyAR(i)
        MyAR(i) = Selection
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    If i = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Matches Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i = LBound(MyAR) To UBound(MyAR)
        Debug.Print MyAR(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```