# Search entire document for String and Select all instances at once

Tags: vba, select, ms-word, find

I am new to VBA. I want to search a Word document for all occurrences of the string "the", and select all the occurrences at once.

Currently, I have this code, which finds the string, but I need to run the subroutine over and over. And it doesn't select all occurrences at once.

```
Sub FindThe()

With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "the"
    .Execute Forward:=True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible, neither in VBA nor the UI.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Word has supported [non-contiguous selections](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/286789/how-to-select-items-that-are-not-next-to-each-other) for ages, at least since 2003. Probably earlier than that, but I don't have an earlier version at hand.

Comment: @GSerg - that isn't the question that was asked. Although you can *manually* construct a non-contiguous selection AFAIK you cannot get Find to select all the occurrences at once.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt With code, you can [with a little bit of effort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10824044/11683). With the interface, there is a tick that does it in the advanced find dialog.

Comment: @GSerg - the code you linked to ***does not*** select the matches. I am well aware that you can call `.Execute` in a loop and process the results, just see all my answers using `Find`. But that is ***not*** what the question asks for. The asks for all the matches to be ***selected*** at once. Which isn't possible even with the advanced find dialog.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Indeed, the multiselection tick has been replaced with a "reading highlight" in newer versions of Word, which is a shame in my opinion. It used to specifically select the words.

Comment: It is possible to do it via menu, at lest in my currect Office365 Word version. Go to advanced find and select Find In - Main Document. This selects all instances. However, even if this asction is recorded as a macro it does not execute in the same way when executed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you may use a code like this to make whatever format or change you want on the found pieces of text, at once:

```
Sub FindThe()
   
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.Bold = False  'Does not find a bold text
        With .Replacement
            .ClearFormatting
            .Font.Bold = True 'Format in bold the found texts
            .Font.Italic = True 'Format in italic the found texts
            .Font.TextColor = wdColorGold 'Format color to Gold for the found texts
        End With
        'Replace all the ocurrences of "the" with "<<Found THE>>"
        .Execute FindText:="the", ReplaceWith:="<<Found THE>>", _
        Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks quite useful. How does one ignore also words in certain color or words that are not in black, for example?